# Calculate percentage based on sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, percentage

Having a mental blank, I need to calculate the percentage of a current number or position, based on it's position between two other numbers, example.

```
var start = 1;
var end = 20;
var currentPos = 10;
```

How can I calculate the `currentPos` value, based as a percentage, obviously it would be 50% but I'm wondering how to calculate this with any variables, example:

```
var start = 11;
var end = 20;
var currentPos = 12;
```

The end and start could potentially be the same value too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you won't have an end and start being the same and `start<=currentPos<=end`

```
var currentPercentile = (currentPos-start)/(end-start);
```

#### Update

if your end and start can be the same value then it can be 100, 0, or unknown since it'd be outside the range, your choice.

```
var currentPercentile = 100;  

if(end-start >0){
  currentPercentile = (currentPos-start)/(end-start);
}
```

Comment: Sorry the start and end could potentially have the same values.

Comment: updated, if they are the same value, you get to choose what you want the value to be, it's either 0, 100, or unknown since it'd be out of the range